# Finding partners for development startup (preferable Germany)

Tags: freelance-websites, group-freelancing, programmer, working-from-home, germany

I am in a difficult situation currently. I am an experienced C++/Qt plus Embedded C/C++ developer. Together with a good friend I planned to open some development service business here in Germany. We are an extremely good match regarding our personality and regarding our technical skills!

Unfortunately he decided to incur serious private liabilities that make him inflexible in matters of time and money while I took the opposite path. I can not consider him a good partner for starting a business anymore. What a pitty.

I tought about starting a business on my own. But I don't think I should do this without one or two people that complete my personal and professional profile in a way that allows serious and reliable development and business operations. I think I really have valuable and essential strengths but also some weaknesses that do not make me a real good "lone wolf" but a good team member.

I know there are a lot of freelancer websites out there. But I should find people based on their *talents* (if possible in Germany; however I worked in an international environment for years so this is not essential).

My questions: 
What is the best way to find such people? Are there any popular freelancer/start-up web services that include systematical team building? Any concrete suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Odesk, Elance, local German forums, local German IT companies,...

Comment: Do Odesk or Elance provide any dedicated functions for finding partners? I know them as services for finding customers only.

Can you recommend any website especially for searching a partner in engineering?

Comment: Finding a business partner is a not easy. Sometimes its just coincident. I too look for partnership in the domain of embedded electronics and software developments. All you have to do is engage in social forums. Find a guy talk to him, make a relation, if you think he is perfect then talk business.

Comment: @Silicomancer Well being partner is a matter of interest. So if a freelancer find your idea lucrative and thinks he can contribute to it, then you will find a partner. So try publishing a job post saying you need a partner and make sure you clearly wrote that you want (a)Partner only and (b)From Germany only. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You should try to find someone with a lot of experience on LinkedIn. People who use freelance websites are usually not looking for a business commitment. That being said it does not mean you cannot find someone on a freelance website.
What I would do (I don't know if it's your case) is find someone with a recommendation from someone like an ex coworker, professor or university colleague.

Also get to know the person and give them some work before jumping into anything to see if you are a good match.